# How to create a custom structure defintion for a plist for Xcode 6.x?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, plugins, plist

To be more explicit, when I have the plist editor open and do a right click, then I can select a Property List Type from a list of available list types that come installed with Xcode 6. It would be great if I can have my custom type appear in this menu. I saw the ones provided by Apple for iOS are compiled in a plugin DVTiOSPlistStructDefs.dvtplugin, this is located in Contents/PlugIns.

Answer (score 0):

sadly you can't do this as simply as you might think.  The only objects you can store in a plist are NSDictionary, NSArray, NSString, NSNumber and NSData.  But you can pretty much represent any kind of object/model graph you could imagine with these classes..

Usually when we load a plist file we'll read it into an NSDictionary object (sometimes an NSArray instead)

```
NSDictionary *theDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:@"aFilePath.plist"];
```

Then from there we'll be able to pull objects of those classes I listed above.  So you'll need to write initialiser method to create your data object or struct from one of those in a method or C function.

eg.

```
//custom initializer
-(instanceType )initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary{

    if (self=[super init]){
    self.floatProperty = [[dictionary objectForKey:@"theFloatKey"]floatValue];
    self.stringProperty = [dictionary objectForKey:@"theStringKey"];
    //etc

    }

return self;
}



//or like this for some struct
myDataStruct structCreateFromDictionary(NSDictionary *dictionary) {

    myDataStruct result;

    result.floatThing = [[dictionary objectForKey:@"theFloatKey"]floatValue];
    result->stringPointer = [dictionary objectForKey:@"theStringKey"];

    //etc

return result;
}
```

Comment: I know how to read the data from a plist, I was referring on how to have custom list type (structure) like the ones provided in Xcode, where you can have default keys and values for dictionaries and drop down lists with multiple allowed values. This way will be much easier for the person who is editing the plist, by just selecting the proper values.

Comment: @Sindrom did you find solution how to do this? Because I also have the same problem and don't understand where to put custom definition..